# asp.net mvc 3, dynamic array

Tags: asp.net, arrays

I am a beginner in ASP.Net MVC 3
I will make a dynamic array initially must show me the first ten elements, and when I click view more displays all array elements

here's what I did:

```
<table>
@foreach (var tweet in Model)
{               
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img alt="" src="@tweet.ProfileImageUrl" />
            <br />
            <input id="rowIDs" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>@tweet.Name</strong>
            <br />
            Friends: <strong>@tweet.FriendsCount</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to put 10 items in the controller,

```
return View(array.Take(10).Skip(page));
```

Do not use the button anymore. Use the pager.
You need to peredovat variable Pag.

Comment: thanks @simply denis ,how to see all the items once I click a button view more

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way(on my opinion) is to create a anchor to the page, itself, with a query string.

Your View must have an anchor like this:

```
<a href="@(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?fullComment=true")">All Comments</a>
```

And relative controller(`HttpGet`, not `HttpPost`(if it has any)) must be something like this:

```
public ViewResult List(bool fullComment=false)
{
    if (fullComment)
        return View(dbContext.EntityList.ToList());
    else
        return View(dbContext.EntityList.Take(5).ToList());
}
```

**Note**: if the page has querystring already, in creating anchor link, in view, you must pay attention to this.